# How to use Next.js <Link> prefetch for a <button>? (And avoiding a double selection while navigating with Tab key)

Tags: next.js, accessibility

Accessibility best practices suggest using `<button>` for button elements.

Prefetching for Next.js can be done via `<Link>`.

However, when you combine the two and use the `Tab` key to navigate, it will essentially select that button twice. E.g.

```
<Link href="#">
  <a>
    This selects once
  </a>
</Link>

<Link href="#">
  <a>
     <button>
       This selects twice
     </button>
  </a>
</Link>
```

You could do something like this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => { window.location.href "#" }
>
  This only selects once
</button>
```

But that doesn't prefetch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `router.prefetch` to fetch the route before going to the page. Check [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerprefetch) for more details

```
export default function Login() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
      router.push('/dashboard')
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/dashboard"); // Prefetch the dashboard page
  }, [])

  return (
      <button onClick={onClick}>Login</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is for nuxt
you don't need to do that way, you can just add props and value into nuxtlink

```
<NuxtLink
 id="home-link"
 :to="localePath('/')"
 exact
 active-class="nav-active"
 tag="button"
 class="btn btn-primary"
  >
   Home/Any Name
</NuxtLink>
```

for next top answer is right

```
export default function Login() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
      router.push('/dashboard')
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/dashboard"); // Prefetch the dashboard page
  }, [])

  return (
      <button onClick={onClick}>Login</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: this is about nextjs and not about nuxtjs !!

Comment: ops sorry my mistake,

Comment: do not include irrelevant answers